# Install plugin from specific branch

Tags: vim, vundle

I'm using `vundle` to install `vim` plugins but I need to install `YouCompleteMe` from the branch `fix-vim-eval-returning-py2-str` because I have to use `python3` and otherwise I get errors.

To do it I have download the `master` branch with `vundle` by `:PluginInstall` then I have to this:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
rm -rf YouCompleteMe
git clone -b fix-vim-eval-returning-py2-str https://github.com/puremourning/YouCompleteMe.git 
cd YouCompleteMe
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

To change the branch.

The problem is that sometimes vundle replace my brunch with `master`  (that is not compatible with my system) and I must leave the line `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` on my `.vimrc` or the plugin doesn't work. How can I workaround?

Comment: From the [issue tracker](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/35) it seems that it is currently not possible to do that with Vundle. However [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) has this feature.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I'm looking for a workaround. I think that I will install ycm without vundle editing some files to allow ycm works in a different directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this work while still using Vundle. After manually switching the branch of your clone with `git`, replace the `Plugin` line with this:

```
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', {'pinned': 1}
```

[The `'pinned'` option](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/9078aafe0248dc3037160449d82b02a4dfb948ad/doc/vundle.txt#L176) “tells Vundle not to perform any git
operations on the plugin, while still adding the existing plugin under the
`bundles` directories to the [runtimepath](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27).” So Vundle will not mess with your clone of YouCompleteMe anymore when you `:PluginUpdate`, it will just load the plugin.

Note that this setting means you will have to update YouCompleteMe yourself, by using `git pull` within the plugin’s directory.

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution I have found. 

However I'm switch to `NeoBundle` that allow to select the `branch`
But thanks anyway